# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable? I can't seem to fix this error

Tags: python, int, typeerror

I have tried rewriting my code multiple times, but I keep getting an error on line 16. Here is my code:

```html
choice = input("fc; cf; fk;?")
if (choice == 'fc'):
 def fc():
  fahrenheit = int(input("enter temp: "))
  celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8
  print(celsius)
 fc()
elif (choice == 'cf'):
 def cf():
  celsius = int(input("enter temp: "))
  fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32
  print(fahrenheit)
 cf()
elif (choice == 'fk'):
 def fk():
  fahrenheit = int(input("enter temp: "))
  kelvin = 5/9(fahrenheit - 32) + 273
  print(kelvin)
 fk()
```

Comment: Random other comments: You might find it easier if you define the functions globally, rather than in the `if` block, and don't use the `()` in the `if` statements - they shouldn't be there in python

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Why should we count 16 lines to find the problem when you could just post the stack trace so we can see the line? What input do you use to get the error? Consider reproducing this problem with fewer lines of code. We shouldn't need to input data and make choices to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

```
kelvin = (5/9)*(fahrenheit - 32) + 273
```

instead of

```
kelvin = 5/9(fahrenheit - 32) + 273
```

should fix it

EDIT: If you are using python 2.7, instead of 5/9, it should be 5.0/9 to force float results.

Comment: How about explaining why.

Comment: Multiplication requires an operator. It is not implicit in most common programming languages, as far as I know. What happens here is that the python interpreter assumes 9 is a function that you are calling with the arguments (fahrenheit - 32). It finds 9 is not a function, but an int and that float object is not callable, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `9(fahrenheit - 32)`. Python sees this as a function call, not multiplication. Operators must always be written explicitly.

```
kelvin = 5/9 * (fahrenheit - 32) + 273
```